# Autocorrection is not working on UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have a `textview` which is derived from another `textview`. I'm setting autocorrection to the derived textview with the following code:

```
textView.autocorrectionType=UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes;  
[textView setNeedsDisplay];
```

But it isn't working, can anyone explain why?

Comment: Please provide more context (source code). Please describe what result you'd expect. And please describe what your code does instead of what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
textView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes;
textView.text = textView.text;
```